# Team Foundation Server plugin for Android Studio - error starting up

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, tfs, azure-devops

I installed [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7961?pr=androidstudio) for Android Studio.

It is for integration with Team Foundation Server version control.

When I start up Android Studio I get the following error:
[image]

I get this error in the event log:

> 09:57:40 StartupAbortedException:
>   com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException:
>   com/microsoft/tfs/core/clients/versioncontrol/exceptions/VersionControlException
>   [Plugin: com.michaelbulava.TFSVCS] 09:58:35 Error Report: Submitted

I do not know what to do as I do not understand the error. I need to use this plugin.

EDIT:

No longer getting this error but Android Studio is freezing after I enter my 'Alternative Credentials'. Basically, the plugin is causing Studio to crash.

Comment: Which version control are you using? Git or TFVC?

Comment: And according to the change notes in the plugin, "Corrected error at startup which caused plugin not to function on IntelliJ 15", you can try with the "0.2.0.150" version to see if it works.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I am using version 0.2.1.200. It's not giving me this error anymore but it does cause Android Studio to hang on startup if I enter my alternative credentials.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I am using TFS

Comment: What's the event log when the plugin hangs?